# Robotium: How to keey the soft keyboard alive after input finished?

Tags: android, automation, robotium

This is my scenario:
1. click the edittext view
2. input something to the EditText view
3. this time, the soft keyboard should be showed
4. Click some other view while the soft keyboard is keep showing

In my environment, after the input finished, the soft keyboard hide immediately
so, is there any method to keep the soft keyboard alive in my scenario?

thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by input finished?

Comment: For example, I set method solo.entertext(view, "abc"); after this method finished, the input finished, and the soft keyboard also hide. what I want is that after the string "abc" displayed in the edit text, the soft keyboard go on show..

Comment: what do solo.entertext(view, "abc") do?

Comment: This method will input the string "adb" to the EditText "view"

Comment: are you doing unit test? don't you input text use hand?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a solo.clickOnView(view) after enterText().

Comment: The question is that the inputed text content will be clear if I do the click again~

Comment: I tried, but the text content will be disappeared after do the solo.clickOnView action. and its very important action especial for the auto suggest action tesing